# change value of input field onclick

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to change the value of an input value with the innerHtml of the button that is clicked ... I have tried a couple of ways but none have worked

```
<script>
   function changeValue(){
     var cValue = document.getElementbyId('technician').innerHTML;
     var cType = document.getElementbyId('type');
     var cType.value = cValue;
    }
</script>

<button id="technician" onclick="changeValue()">Technician</button>
<input type="" id="type" name="type" value="change"></input>
```

I also tried

```
<script>
   function changeValue(){
     var cValue = document.getElementbyId('technician').innerhtml;
     document.getElementbyId('type').value = ('cValue');
    }
</script>
```

neither seems to be working

Comment: Try innerText instead of innerHtml. If that is not working try to use document.getElementbyId('technician').value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have several typos in your code
uppercase and lowercase letters do matter in things like getElementById and innerHTML

i believe this is what you're trying to do:

```html
<script>
   function changeValue(o){
     document.getElementById('type').value=o.innerHTML;
    }
</script>

<button id="technician" onclick="changeValue(this)">Technician</button>
<button id="developer" onclick="changeValue(this)">Developer</button>
<input type="text" id="type" name="type" value="change" />
```

Comment: I do not see the typos you are referring to... I was able to fix the problem..  answered it above. Your code woks as well. Actually better than mine. My code is more weighted. Thank you

Comment: typos are literally in using a lowercase letter instead of uppercase. getElement**b**yId is not the same as getElement**B**yId. also inner**html** is not the same as inner**HTML**

Comment: that was a typo in this question... sorry.. in the actual code it was correct

Answer (score 2):

Here's a REALLY simple way to do it:

```js
function changeValue(value) {
  document.getElementById('button1').innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeValue('This content has changed.')" id="button1">I have some content that will change when you click on me.</button>
```

I hope that this example helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="technician" onclick="changeValue()">Technician</button>
<input type="" id="type" name="type" value="change"></input>
<script>
   function changeValue(){
        document.getElementById('type').value="There you go";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<script>
   function changeValue(){
     document.getElementById('technician').innerHTML = document.getElementById('type').value;
    }
</script>
<button id="technician" onclick="changeValue()">Technician</button>
<input id="type" name="type" value="change"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers. My problem was, when I called the var cVaue I enclosed it

```
document.getElementbyId('type').value = ('cValue');
```

When I should have the code like this

```
document.getElementbyId('type').value = cValue;
```